# Javascript Date working strange

Tags: javascript, datetime

I was working with Javascript `Date` and faced strange problem.

```
date1 = new Date(1970, 1, 1);
date2 = new Date("1970-01-01T13:00:00.000Z");
console.log(date1.getYear());  //70
console.log(date1.getMonth()); //1
console.log(date1.getDay());   //0 expect 1
console.log(date2.getYear());  //70
console.log(date2.getMonth()); //0 expect 1
console.log(date2.getDay());   //4 expect 1
```

Why this result happened? What I am doing wrong with `Date` Object?
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/FKxR4/150/)

UPDATE:

```
console.log(date1);
```

shows this result.

```
Date 1970-01-31T14:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `new Date(year, month, date)`, month is 0 based, so 1 is not January but `february`, so your `date1` and `date2` are different dates. Then, the function getDay returns 0 to 6, that corresponds to Monday to Sunday. If you want the date, you have to use getDate instead.

Comment: You are right, Can you answer more about UPDATE question?

Comment: new Date uses local time. So, you would be pointing to 1970-02-01, but you are in a local time GMT minus-something, and so you see the previous day, 1970-01-31. In my computer, as I'm in GMT +1, I see 1970-02-01. Check Date documentation and Date.UTC function. Dates are quite complicated... I recommend you to check also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Thanks I see, great